# Redirecting user to Login OpenID page

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

I am currently implementing and at the same time learning the use of OpenId. Specifically using [lightopenid](https://gitorious.org/lightopenid). It is working but I would like users that are needing to login to be redirected automatically to the login page when accessing the url www.example.com/login. The example below has the user click on a button and then redirects the user to the login page. How can I redirect the user automatically with url www.example.com/login to the open ID login page?

```
# Logging in with Google accounts requires setting special identity, so this example shows how to do it.
require 'openid.php';
try {
    # Change 'localhost' to your domain name.
    $openid = new LightOpenID('localhost');
    if(!$openid->mode) {
        if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
            $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
            header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
        }
?>
<form action="?login" method="post">
    <button>Login with Google</button>
</form>
<?php
    } elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
        echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
    } else {
        echo 'User ' . ($openid->validate() ? $openid->identity . ' has ' : 'has not ') . 'logged in.';
    }
} catch(ErrorException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simple use this in your singin page

```
<?php // index.php
require_once 'openid.php';
$openid = new LightOpenID("www.example.com");
$openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
$openid->returnUrl = 'http://www.example.com/login';
header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
?>
```